# How can I write a bash script that waits for other nodes in a cluster?

Tags: bash, unix, concurrency, cluster-computing

Slightly weird question here! Brief outline:

- I'm trying to write an install script to do automatic install of mysql cluster on multiple nodes
- I have a script which runs, and exits (code 0) if all mcm daemons are not up yet. This is fine.
- The run on the final node does the cluster setup.

However, so that I can provision these boxes in any order or even at the same time, I'd like to attempt to implement some kind of network-latch-semaphore-election type thing, the idea being:

1. Node A comes up, detects the lack of daemon on B and C, and waits.
2. Node B comes up, detects the lack of daemon on C, and waits.
3. Node C comes up, finds all daemons up, and then (by some heuristic) tells the others to exit and continues on with the configuration.

Equally, in step 3, any other node could get selected as the 'leader' and configure the cluster, telling the others to exit.

What I need then, is some kind of mechanism (maybe a listening netcat socket?) that blocks the script until the others are ready, and can then kill the other scripts to continue on it's own.

Is this even possible in bash, or should I look at converting my script into Python?

---

EDIT:

At the moment, my basic inter-node communication is as simple as this:

```
for node in ${nodelist[@]}
do
    nc -z -w 1 $node 1862 || failure=1
    [ ! -z $failure ] && echo "mcmd on $node not listening!" && exit 0
done

## Begin cluster configuration process...
```

But, this requires me to start the final node once everything else is up.
As I said, this is working fine, but I wondered (more as an academic excercise) if there was some way I could do a simple 'election' type process to do the configuration.

At the moment I'm leaning towards a listening netcat process that waits for a specific command. I merely wondered if anyone had done anything similar before.

Comment: What do you have already? And since you're just getting started I would very strongly recommend using Python or another modern language instead of Bash.

Comment: @l0b0 I've updated the question. I'm quite familiar with bash, as I spend a lot of my working day with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've ended up implementing this still doesn't quite solve the race condition, but does allow me to run the same commands on all nodes (rather than deciding which node to run the post install script on).

I now have:

```
failure=""
for node in ${nodelist[@]}
do
    # check for mcmd service
    nc -z -w 1 $node 1862 || failure=1
done
if [ ! -z $failure ]
then
    echo "Waiting for nodes..."
    nc -l 6688 >/dev/null
    echo "Told to quit."
    exit 0
fi
## This block runs IFF all hosts listening on 1862.
for node in ${nodelist[@]}
do
    echo "quit" | nc -w 1 $node 6688 || echo "No process waiting on $node."
done

## Begin cluster configuration process...
```

What this does (in summary) is open a socket if a node isn't listening on the service socket (1862). That blocks execution until the socket is closed, which will only happen once all nodes are up.

This means I can run my install process as:

```
rpm -Uvh my-custom-package.rpm && sudo /path/to/config_cluster.sh <args>
```

...which can be the same on all nodes. This mostly achieves what I wanted, although there are still some situations it might go wrong!